# Передача переменной jquery в PHP файл

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

Всем привет.
Есть таблица jqGrid,и при выборе строки срабатывает событие onSelectRow и получаю значение,которое записывается в myCellData.

```html
editurl: 'tovaredit.php',
datatype: "json",
mtype: 'POST',
onSelectRow: function (sel_id) {
                       var grid = $('#jqGrid');
        var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
        var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'idtov');
                        }
```

Как передать значение переменной и использовать её в php файле,в котором идёт обработка операций edit,add,del jqgrid?

Comment: добавляйте ее как query string в editurl

Comment: Я пытался вот так:
Задал переменную ur вне функции ,и внутри функции задал ur=myCellData. А edit изменил так: editurl: 'tovaredit.php?idtov='+ur ,но всё равно выдаёт tovaredit.php?idtov=undefined
А где можно почитать про query srting? Гугл конкретного не даёт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onSelectRow: function (sel_id) {
  var grid = $('#jqGrid');
  var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
  var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'idtov');
  grid.setGridParam({'editurl':'tovaredit.php?idtov=' + myCellData});
}
```